# Export product image with Commerce Cart API module

Tags: commerce, 9, uri

I'm usng the "Commerce Cart API" module on my website to build a custom cart js layer.
The problem i am facing is the purchased entity has a field_image field and I would like get the url of that images instead of the file id.

The json response of cart?_format=json looks like the following:

```
    [
  {
    "order_id": 9,
    "uuid": "a4604a10-f956-41e7-87f6-0d745b9345a4",
    "order_number": null,
    "store_id": 2,
    "order_items": [
      {
        "order_item_id": 12,
        "uuid": "33bca307-2ee1-4be4-9599-9ecf3604f83c",
        "order_id": 9,
        "purchased_entity": {
          "variation_id": 1181,
          "uuid": "8112b394-5008-4209-85dc-a9deaf5dfea1",
          "type": "default",
          "product_id": 470,
          "sku": "345",
          "title": "Glade Aerosol 330",
          "list_price": {
            "number": "1.000000",
            "currency_code": "ARS",
            "formatted": "ARS 1,00"
          },
          "price": {
            "number": "2.000000",
            "currency_code": "ARS",
            "formatted": "ARS 2,00"
          },
          "resolved_price": {
            "number": "4.000000",
            "currency_code": "ARS",
            "formatted": "ARS 4,00"
          },
          "field_imagenes": [
            122
          ]
```

In brief what i'm tring to get is field_imagenes as an array of image urls.
Is there a way to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's reasonable for you to move to [Commerce API](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_api)?

That module is based on JSONA:API, therefore you should be able to get the data of relationship entities quite easily, [look at include\relationship example on docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/includes).

Plus, the headless system on Drupal mostly prefer json:api, including  [commerce itself](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cart_api/issues/3118810)

Comment: That could be an option. Thanks!